# Number of combinations: Allocation of balls of k different colors to n buckets

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

While analyzing an algorithm, I encountered the following problem. I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction (e.g., Catalan numbers, Motzkin numbers, etc.).

Let there be $n$ buckets and balls with $k$ different colors $\{1, 2, ..., k\}$. There are $j_1$ balls of color 1, $j_2$ balls of color 2, ..., and $j_k$ balls of color k ($j_i \in \{0, 1, ..., n\}$ for all $i \in \{1, 2, ..., k\}$). Buckets with two or more balls of the same color are not allowed. It might contain balls of all colors, however.

Given $n$, $k$, $j_1$, ..., and $j_k$, I want to answer the question of how many combinations have balls of all $k$ colors in at least one bucket. Balls of the same color are indistinguishable. The buckets are labeled.

Example: $n = 2$ buckets, $k = 2$ colors, $j_1 = 1$ ball of color 1, $j_2 = 1$ ball of color 2. Then, there are two combinations with both balls in one of the two buckets.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can approach this naively using inclusion-exclusion, i.e. the number with at least one bucket having all colors is those with all colors in bucket 1 $ +$ all colors in bucket 2 $ + \dotsb -$ all colors in both buckets 1 and 2 etc.

If there is one ball of each color in bucket 1, then the rest can be chosen in any way. For each color $i$, we have $j_i - 1$ balls to put into $n-1$ buckets giving us $\binom{n - 1}{j_i - 1}$ ways. Combining these give us $\prod_{i=1}^k \binom{n - 1}{j_i - 1}$. The same is true for bucket 2, 3, etc. so there are $n \prod_{i=1}^k \binom{n - 1}{j_i - 1}$ in total. But we have overcounted. By a similar argument, we see that there are $\prod_{i=1}^k \binom{n - 2}{j_i - 2}$ ways with buckets 1 and 2 having all colors and $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to choose the two buckets that have all colors. Continuing this and applying inclusion-exclusion gives us the final formula $$\sum_{m=1}^{\min j} (-1)^{m+1} \binom{n}{m} \prod_{i=1}^k \binom{n - m}{j_i - m}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tested it with some more examples; it seems to produce the correct results.